# Flexbox is not side by side on Safari

Tags: safari, flexbox

I am trying to put the divs side by side with flexbox, but on safari for mac is not working.
Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer 11 it is working.
Someone can help me? hehe

[all browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81gG0.jpg)

[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD6qd.jpg)

It looks like the white block has box-sizing: content-box, but it does not have...

Does anyone know why?
The code: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rnr56buk/)

```css
.flex {
 display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
 display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box-full {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
.box-fridge {
  &:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }

  .block-left {
    padding: 21px 22px;
    flex-grow: 2;
  }

  .block-right {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    background-color: #4681A8;
    max-width: 190px;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .title-fridge {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 29px;
  }

  .desc {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 15px;
    margin-top: 17px;
  }

  .block {
    align-self: center;
    color: #fff;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  .price {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 29px;
  }

  .period {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}
```

Comment: The main problem here is that you have combined Flexbox and float, where you made the flex items to also have `float: left`. That won't work properly cross browsers, so either get rid of Flexbox or float

Comment: you are right about this, @LGSon, but still not working on safari :(

Comment: For the reason I just said. Fix the code and come back if it still won't work.